# ServiceSecurityContext is null with Castle Windsor WCF Integration Facility

Tags: .net, wcf, castle-windsor, wcf-binding

I'm trying to use WCF Integration Facility with Castle. So far I have the server and the client working fine. The server is hosted in IIS 7 (with a SVC file with no code behind).

Now I need to know the username of the client. For this I'm doing:

```
OperationContext oc = OperationContext.Current;
ServiceSecurityContext ssc = oc.ServiceSecurityContext;
```

But the ssc is null. I guess it has something to do with enabling TransportCredentialOnly on binding, but I don't have any bindings (using .NET 4 Default Bindings - through the Facility).

So the question boils down to:

How can I get the client username in a WCF Integration Facility hosted service on the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems for Wcf/Castle related issues, Castle google group is much more useful. In case you land here, the answer can be found in this thread of the Castle Google Group:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/castle-project-devel/VOQKW4XlvLM